# Coreservice : Upload Binary File (Couldn't upload the binary file Provided access token has expired)

Tags: core-service, web8

I'm trying to upload binaries in the new Web 8 way.  (i've got a few gigs worth to upload).

Each time I try and upload a file, I run the following code:

```
StreamUploadClient _UploadClient = null;
_UploadClient = new StreamUploadClient(_endpointConfigNameUpload);
var userCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_username, _password, _domain);                                 _UploadClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = userCredential;
AccessTokenData token = CoreServiceClient.GetCurrentUser();

fileUpload = _UploadClient.UploadBinaryContent(token, file.OpenRead());
```

and once the component is saved, I do the following:

```
_UploadClient.Close();
_UploadClient.Dispose();
```

After a few mins I get an error that :

> Couldn't upload the binary file Provided access token has expired

I have performed the 2013 compatibility in my CME hoping this would stop the token from expiring (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US&docid=GUID-879B67A8-71BA-4BBD-9CCE-9140B860904E&query=%2B%22AccessTokenData%22)

I've also tried adding 24 hours to the token via the token.ExpiresAt(DateTime)

But none of these changes help me with my issue.   Has anyone got any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi John, i had same issue, my work around is renew the access token if it will expire in the next 30 seconds. if (accessToken.ExpiresAt <= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)) works for me

Comment: how do you renew it @LucasLiu?   can you paste the solution as your answer? thanks

Comment: Access Tokens expire for security reasons.. Obviously, you can't make them expire later by simply changing the expiration date/time in the Access Token; that would defeat the purpose of expiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the quick way is checking expireAt from the access token, close current client if expires in 30 seconds and create an new client.

```
    public void UpdateAccessToken()
    {
        AccessTokenData accessToken = client.GetCurrentUser();
        if (accessToken.ExpiresAt <= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30))
        {
            client.Close();
            this.ConntectSDLCloud();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lucas, see http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14996/accesstoken-configure-time on how to configure the default value and avoid the constant round-tripping here (you may still want this if you want specific events to 'refresh' the token I guess).

Comment: i didn't get that value to work @Dylan..MarkSaunders

Comment: ahh that's a shame - I'll leave it here for a few days in case Kunal updates (perhaps a specific restart or something along those lines is required) .. otherwise I'll delete the link :-/

Comment: i cannot change the timeout value on SDL Cloud, but have to detect expiry time plus 30 seconds (time to call back). this works...