# AccessToken - configure time?

Tags: core-service, web8

In relation to this question: [Coreservice : Upload Binary File (Couldn't upload the binary file Provided access token has expired)](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14942/coreservice-upload-binary-file-couldnt-upload-the-binary-file-provided-acces)

I'm wondering if there's a way to configure the 'default' time for the access token, it seems to be roughly 5 minutes as default.

I've had a look in the contentmanager.config and couldn't see anywhere specifically.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Tridion.ContentManager.config** file, look for the **accessTokenExpiration** setting.
This has now been documented and for future versions it will be added to the MMC SnapIn console as well.

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-4AE3B998-FD3F-460F-BFAE-A7401BE88B34

As with the Credential Cache Expiration setting, the default value is 300s (5min).

Answer (score 7):

John,

The access token is generated after you login and the timeout for that is set using Credential Cache Expiration which by default is set to 300 seconds = 5 minutes ;)

[image]

Comment: I take back the right answer, this doesn't seem to have any impact :(

Comment: AFAIK, this should be where the exipration timespan is taken from.